# How to remove handwritten marks on digital text images with Python

Tags: image, opencv3.0, python-tesseract

[image]I am new to image processing and trying to convert text from text images but it is not giving exact results as the marks on the text are creating error in output text.

Comment: C26) Who has been appointed as the new
Managingï¬‚ Director of National Housing

Bank(NHB) )? 21 Â® i a:

A.Sarada Kumar Hota
B. Sriram Kalyanaraman
C. Rakshita Das
D.Mahesh Patidar

Comment: above is output text